# Uploading Multiple Images django REST

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, imagefield

I would like to upload multiple images using the Django model field(ImageField).
I created a model and was able to upload multiple images on the admin side like so https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5dpZ.jpg
I got the idea here (https://github.com/raszidzie/Multiple-Images-Django-Tutorial) in the Post(admin.py)

```
admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import School,SchoolImage

class SchoolImageAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SchoolImage

@admin.register(School)
class SchoolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=('school_name','school_type',"school_country")
    search_fields=('school_name','school_type',"school_country")
    list_filter=('school_name','school_type','school_gender')
    inlines = [SchoolImageAdmin]

    class Meta:
        model =School

@admin.register(SchoolImage)

class SchoolImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

I created the SchoolImage Model to handle multiple images in admin.py

```
models.py
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
from partial_date import PartialDateField

class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    school_country = CountryField()
    school_city = models.CharField(max_length= 30,default= None)
    school_population = models.IntegerField()
    school_description = models.TextField(max_length = 300)
    year_build = PartialDateField()
    total_branches = models.IntegerField()
    school_fees = models.IntegerField()
    school_images = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.school_name 

class SchoolImage(models.Model):
    schoolImages = models.ImageField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.school.school_name
```

not sure how to make it work in the veiws

here is my views code

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status
from .models import School
from .serializers import *

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def school_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = School.objects.all()
        serializer = SchoolSerializer(data, context={'request': request},many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SchoolSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response( status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

How do I make it work in my views??

Comment: could you please show what is `multiple images in the admin side`

Comment: @Fannigurt here is the multiple images on admin side ` https://imgur.com/BzVDPC5`